# My keyless Car won't start after having a flat battery, message:FORD KEY FREE IGNITION PRESS POWER OFF OK

Tags: starting

Ford Focus 2011, after flat battery will not start, get the message: FORD KEY FREE IGNITION PRESS POWER OFF OK This is the keyless start version.

Answer (score 1):

I'll need more information. Are you sure the message isn't: "FORD KEYFREE SWITCH IGNITION OFF PRESS POWER"?

That's the closest I can get, using to the [2012 manual](http://www.motorcraftservice.com/pubs/content/~WOCFOC/~MUS~LEN/40/12focog1e.pdf).

Are the accessories coming on when you try? If so, then it is switching modes properly but may not be able to communicate with the fob to authorize the engine to start. You may need to hold the keyfob near the steering column. This is according to page 263, where if the keyfob does not have enough power to respond.

That message just indicates that the system is ready, from what I understand. Pressing the ignition button should switch to ACC/ON modes and with a working keyfob, start the car. There are seperate messages that let you know your keyfob isn't working.